# fancyhdr alphabetical chapter problem in frontmatter of book

Tags: header-footer, chapters, fancyhdr, front-matter

Here a not-so MWE:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{a4wide}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage[spelling=new,babelshorthands=true]{german}
\usepackage[autostyle]{csquotes}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[style=authortitle-icomp,backref=true,backrefstyle=two+,hyperref=true,isbn=false,backend=biber,citereset=chapter,bibencoding=utf8]{biblatex}


\defbibheading{caption}{
    \phantomsection
    \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{#1}
    \section*{#1}%
    \markboth{#1}{#1}
}
\pagestyle{fancyplain}
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]%
{\markboth{\thechapter.\ #1}{}}
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]%
{\markright{\thesection\ #1}}
\lhead[\fancyplain{}{\bfseries\thepage}]%
{\fancyplain{}{\bfseries\rightmark}}
\rhead[\fancyplain{}{\bfseries\leftmark}]%
{\fancyplain{}{\bfseries\thepage}}
\cfoot{}

\renewcommand\thechapter{\Alph{chapter}}

\begin{document}
\frontmatter
\tableofcontents
\chapter{First Chapter}
\lipsum[1-10]
\mainmatter
\chapter{Second Chapter}

\end{document}
```

My problem: I want alphabetical numbering for the chapters, that's why I use `\renewcommand\thechapter{\Alph{chapter}}`. But for the first chapter, which is in the frontmatter and has the number 0, there is no character, therefore it just prints:

[image]

I want to remove the `.` before the first chapter in the frontmatter. How do I achieve this? Note that I have redefined `\chaptermark` in the preamble. I just need the right `\if...` statement in there. Can someone help?

Cheers

Comment: `\Alph` or `\alph` has no output if the counter is zero

Comment: yup that's what I wrote. I want to remove the dot so that it doesn't look stupid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's possible to check for the chapter number in `\markboth`:

`\ifnum\value{chapter} = 0 \thechapter\else\thechapter.\fi`

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{a4wide}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage[spelling=new,babelshorthands=true]{german}
\usepackage[autostyle]{csquotes}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[style=authortitle-icomp,backref=true,backrefstyle=two+,hyperref=true,isbn=false,backend=biber,citereset=chapter,bibencoding=utf8]{biblatex}


\defbibheading{caption}{
    \phantomsection
    \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{#1}
    \section*{#1}%
    \markboth{#1}{#1}
}
\pagestyle{fancyplain}
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]%
{\markboth{\ifnum\value{chapter} = 0 \thechapter\else\thechapter.\fi\ #1}{}}
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]%
{\markright{\thesection\ #1}}
\lhead[\fancyplain{}{\bfseries\thepage}]%
{\fancyplain{}{\bfseries\rightmark}}
\rhead[\fancyplain{}{\bfseries\leftmark}]%
{\fancyplain{}{\bfseries\thepage}}
\cfoot{}

\renewcommand\thechapter{\Alph{chapter}}
% In case there is a section:
%\renewcommand{\thesection}{\ifnum\value{chapter} = 0 \arabic{section}\else \thechapter.\arabic{section}\fi}


\begin{document}

\frontmatter
\tableofcontents
\chapter{First Chapter}
\lipsum[1-10]
\mainmatter
\chapter{Second Chapter}

\lipsum[1-10]

\end{document}
```

Comment: @Philipp: Yes, but the next problem is a `\section` ;-)

Comment: But section is not \Alpha, so no problem AFAIK

Comment: But `\thesection` is `\thechapter.\arabic{section}` and `\thechapter` will yield nothing then, leaving `.1` for the section number

Comment: Ah that's fine, this chapter doesn't have a section lucky me :) But thank's I'll remember that

Comment: @Philipp: I've added the relevant code, but used a `%` in front of it.